# Spring <form:select> tag causing error in Spring mvc + Hibernate app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

First of all I'd like to say that I've searched for the solution all over the Internet and SO, but found no solution for this particular situation. I am just learning about java web programming. I am making simple mvc app for adding teachers to MySQL database. DB has only 3 tables: 'teacher', 'title' and join table 'teacher_title'. 'title' is a lookup table, with 'title_id' / 'title_description' values.
In my jsp page I have drop-down list for selecting the teacher title (e.g. PhD, MSc, etc.), 2 input fields for entering the first name and the last name of the teacher and a submit/save button.

This is my controller:

```
    /**
     * Handles and retrieves the add teacher page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAddTeacher(Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to show add teacher page");

        // Add to model
        model.addAttribute("teacherAttribute", new Teacher());
        model.addAttribute("titleList", titleService.getAll());

        return "addTeacher";
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new teacher by delegating the processing to TeacherService.
     * Displays a confirmation JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAddTeacher(@RequestParam(value = "id") Integer titleId, 
                                @ModelAttribute("teacherAttribute") Teacher teacher) {

        logger.debug("Received request to add new teacher");

        // Call TeacherService to do the actual adding
        teacherService.add(titleId, teacher);

        return "addTeacherSuccess";
    }
```

This is the important part of addTeacher.jsp page:

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/teacher/add?id=titleId" />
<form:form modelAttribute="teacherAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
        <form:label path="title">Title:</form:label>
        <form:select path="title" id="titleSelect">
            <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
            <form:options items="${titleList}" itemValue="titleId" itemLabel="titleDescription" />              
        </form:select>
...
```

This is Teacher entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TEACHER_ID")
    private Integer techerId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="teacher_title",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="TITLE_ID")
                )
    private Title title;
// getters and setters
}
```

This is Title entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TITLE_ID")
    private Integer titleId;

    @Column(name = "TITLE_DESCRIPTION", length = 10)
    private String titleDescription;
// getters and setters
}
```

And just in case, these are Teacher and Title services, respectively:

```
    /**
     * Adds new teacher
     */
    public void add(Integer titleId, Teacher teacher) {

        logger.debug("Adding new teacher");

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // Retrieve existing title via id
        Title existingTitle = (Title) session.get(Title.class, titleId);

        // Add title to teacher
        teacher.setTitle(existingTitle);

        // Persists to db
    session.save(teacher);
    }
```

.

```
    /**
     * Retrieves a list of titles
     */
    public List<Title> getAll() {

        logger.debug("Retrieving all titles");

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Title");

        List<Title> titleList = castList(Title.class, query.list());

        return titleList;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
        List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
        for(Object o: c)
          r.add(clazz.cast(o));
        return r;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a single title
     */
    public Title get(Integer titleId) {

        logger.debug("Retrieving single title");

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // Retrieve existing title
        Title title = (Title) session.get(Title.class, titleId);

        return title;
    }
```

What I've managed to understand so far is that the problem is with the select tag in my jsp. When I comment out select tag and eneter the parameter manually (e.g. URL?id=1), saving to the DB works just fine. Otherwise I get the following error: "HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.". I have searched the Internet for this error too, but found no applicable solutions.

It is just beyond my humble knowledge to determine where I'm making a mistake. Thank you in advance.

**Update**:
This is new controller method for adding new teacher, where `@RequestParam`'s `value` attribute was changed from `id` to `title`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddTeacher(@RequestParam(value = "title") Integer titleId, 
@ModelAttribute("teacherAttribute") Teacher teacher) {

logger.debug("Received request to add new teacher");

// Call TeacherService to do the actual adding
teacherService.add(titleId, teacher);

// This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addTeacherSuccess.jsp
return "addTeacherSuccess";
```

}

And this is new addTeacher.jsp, where `?id=titleId` was deleted from URL:

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/teacher/add" />
<form:form modelAttribute="teacherAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
        <form:label path="title">Title:</form:label>
        <form:select path="title" id="titleSelect">
            <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
            <form:options items="${titleList}" itemValue="titleId" itemLabel="titleDescription" />              
        </form:select>
...
```

Still getting the same error as before.

Here is the error I'm getting (and I don't understand):

```
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:getMethodArgumentValues:166) Error resolving argument [1] [type=com.jovana.domain.Teacher]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.jovana.controller.MainController]
Method [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]

org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:getMethodArgumentValues:166) Error resolving argument [1] [type=com.jovana.domain.Teacher]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.jovana.controller.MainController]
Method [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]

org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:resolveException:132) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:resolveException:132) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:resolveException:132) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:resolveException:132) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:resolveException:132) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:resolveException:132) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.jovana.controller.MainController.postAddTeacher(java.lang.Integer,com.jovana.domain.Teacher)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'teacherAttribute' on field 'title': rejected value [4]; codes [typeMismatch.teacherAttribute.title,typeMismatch.title,typeMismatch.com.jovana.domain.Title,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [teacherAttribute.title,title]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.jovana.domain.Title' for property 'title'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.jovana.domain.Title] for property 'title': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (DispatcherServlet.java:processDispatchResult:999) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (DispatcherServlet.java:processDispatchResult:999) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (FrameworkServlet.java:resetContextHolders:1028) Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5f57b190
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (FrameworkServlet.java:resetContextHolders:1028) Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5f57b190
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (FrameworkServlet.java:processRequest:966) Successfully completed request
[DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (FrameworkServlet.java:processRequest:966) Successfully completed request
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:publishEvent:332) Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testLookupTable/essays/main/teacher/add]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[72089007DB0E4468BA90CDA44FCA8CC0]; user=[null]; time=[144ms]; status=[OK]
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:publishEvent:332) Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testLookupTable/essays/main/teacher/add]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[72089007DB0E4468BA90CDA44FCA8CC0]; user=[null]; time=[144ms]; status=[OK]
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:publishEvent:332) Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testLookupTable/essays/main/teacher/add]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[72089007DB0E4468BA90CDA44FCA8CC0]; user=[null]; time=[144ms]; status=[OK]
[TRACE] [http-bio-8080-exec-7 11:10:38] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:publishEvent:332) Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testLookupTable/essays/main/teacher/add]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[72089007DB0E4468BA90CDA44FCA8CC0]; user=[null]; time=[144ms]; status=[OK]
```

**Solution** (thank you storm_buster) is adding this to the controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Title.class, "title", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
         @Override
         public void setAsText(String text) {
            setValue((text.equals(""))?null:titleService.getTitle(Integer.parseInt((String)text)));
         }
     });
}
```

The end!

Comment: You should post less verbose questions, it is really hard to understand. You could start with removing uneccessary getters and setters...

Comment: I'm guessing `add?id=titleId` should be `add?id=${titleId}`?

Comment: @Bart I tried this, but what is being sent is `add?id= `. Seems like `${titleId}` is empty (like selecting the item from the list is not even working). Any idea why?

Comment: What's being outputted when you set the log level to TRACE on *org.springframework*? It should show what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this error because you are using

> @ModelAttribute("teacherAttribute") Teacher teacher)

Spring is unable to convert your requestParam "title" ( which is string ) to a Title class which belongs to a Teacher Entity.

You have two solution : 
1- add this to your controller

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Title.class, "title", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
         @Override
         public void setAsText(String text) {
            setValue((text.equals(""))?null:titleService.getTitle(Integer.parseInt((String)text)));
         }
     });
}
```

2- Modify your requestmapping as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddTeacher(@RequestParam(value = "title") Integer titleId, 
@RequestParam("teacherAttribute") Integer teacherId) {
```

And add a new Interface:

```
teacherService.add(titleId, teacherId);
```

Comment: '@storm_buster' It won't let me tag you in my comment, so I had to add quotes just to show your username. Also, thank you for the explanation... Is there anything I can do for your reputation score beside accepting your answer? I don't have permission to vote up the answer... :/

Comment: @just_a_girl I think it is ok. Just glad that it worked. Feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

`<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/teacher/add?id=titleId" />`

You don't need to write params as `?id=titleId` manually, it will be added automatically. In this case in request body (because it's POST request).

Also `path` attribute in form tag and `value` of `@RequestParam` in controller attributes must be the same. So write, for example `@RequestParam(value = "title") Integer titleId`

Comment: Ok, if I lose ?id=titleId in jsp, and @RequestParam(value="id") Integer titleId in handler method, how do I access the titleId in controller (because I need to pass it to the teacherService)? Sorry for asking such a beginner question...

Comment: When you'll give same names to `<form:select path="title" ..` and `@RequestParam(value = "title") ..` Spring will bind value and put in your `titleId` variable

Comment: I understand, I did what you said (removed `?id=titleId` and renamed 'id' to 'title' in @RequestParam) but I still get the same error ("The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.") :(

Comment: do you know how to tell the controller about `itemValue="titleId"` from the `<form:options ...>` tag, I believe that is what it expects? Or am I wrong? BTW Max Vasileusky I don't know how to tag you in my comment, '@Max Vasileusky' doesn't work...

Comment: `itemValue` is used to fill list. If it's all right with drop-down list, then it's all right with `itemValue` :) If you are using Chrome you can press F12, open Network tab, send request from page and see if its params look as expected. (there are similar tools in other browsers too)

Comment: I've tried what you said in Chrome and the only thing I can see being sent is `URL;jsessionid=F1400F4C8A5E0C5DE6ED4A1F51E1D9F6`... Help... I'm thinking about jumping off a cliff :)

Comment: @just_a_girl You could also add your shiny new controller method to your question. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163251/chrome-source-of-post-data on how to use Chrome to see the posted data.

Comment: The posted data look like this: `"text": "title=3&firstName=fhhtfht&lastName=tghy"` So, title is 3, which is what I selected and is valid id for title. Now I'm even more confused, I thought that the problem was here...

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you - @Bart

Comment: @just_a_girl Please post your up-to-date controller method which is mapped to that request.

Comment: @Bart I have posted my up-to-date controller method in the **Update** section at the end of my post above.