# Python submit tags with requests

Tags: javascript, python, html, tags, python-requests

So, i need to set tags for the video that i upload, but i can't get it to work.
This is the tags form:

```html
<input id="video_keywords" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" onchange="checkTags()" onkeyup="checkTags()" size="72" name="keywords" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

And this is my code so far:

```
payload = {
      'keywords': 'tag1 tag2 tag3',
      'APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS': apc,
      'message' : '',
  }
  files = {'upload_file' : (open("D:\\CPA\\videos\\watermarked\\test.avi", 'rb'))}
  url = 'http://upload.site.com/account/uploads/submit?video_type=other'
  r = s.post(url,data = payload,files = files,headers = headers)
```

I've tried lots of different things, formatting the tags as a list with and without a space between, i tried encoding the string into json, the website still returns a message that the tags need to be submitted.
Anyone has any idea as to what i'm doing wrong?

And another thing, while inspecting the http headers/requests in a browser, i've noticed that whenever i type tags i receive a GET request from the site, looking like this :
`GET /account/title_blacklist/?title=tag1%20tag2` (maybe this is useful?)

Comment: what language is that `code` in?

Comment: OK - saw the `javascript` tag and wondered

Comment: That specific form might be invoking Javascript, so that's why i added that tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of potential reasons this isn't working, but there's not enough information here to be certain why.  Here are a couple potential reasons:

- Most likely, the `checkTags()` Javascript function is performing some sort of validation on the tags.  Judging by the GET request you showed, it's doing some AJAX to the server, and it's probably looking for blacklisted tags.  Or, it could just be sending them to the server to have their format "validated" (less likely).  In order to test this out, I'd try playing around with some GET requests to that URL, putting different tags in the GET parameters.  By seeing what comes out, you might get a better idea of what tags you're allowed to send.  You might also try using your browser's developer tools (like [Chrome's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163251/chrome-source-of-post-data)) to view the POST data as you send it to this form.
- It's also possible that there is some sort of [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token in the form.  The server generates such a token when it sends the form, and it's valid for a short period of time afterwards.  It is sent back to the server with the form data.  The server will check the token for validity when it receives the form.  It exists to prevent other people (especially malicious websites) from submitting form data to their form.  It could be that, for security reasons, the server won't mention the CSRF token in its response, and instead says that the tags are the reason for the error.

All of these possibilities can be checked by examining the requests the webpage sends in the developer tools, and also examining the entire source of the `<form>`, not just that specific `<input>`.  Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Unfortunately, i only see GET requests when i monitor the browser with Live HTTP Headers and Firebug. I can't see the POST request i send to the browser.

Comment: I'm able to see POST requests in Chrome's developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I), Network tab.  You can even sort by request type, and you can see the request headers and body right there.

Comment: Wow, i actually solved it. I saw the POST headers in Chrome's developer's tools and i saw that the form was actually supposed to be named 'tags', and not keywords. It's so simple i feel like an idiot. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Good job! I'm glad you were able to find the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
The form was actually supposed to be called with 'tags', and not by it's name.
It's kinda weird, but it's solved now.