# HTTP POST payload not visible in Chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, post, http-post, google-chrome-devtools

I have checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163251/chrome-source-of-post-data). However, my debugger looks like below.

## Failure example

[image: No form data, No raw content].

No form data, No raw content

Raw example (* Although path is different from the screen capture, both of them are unable to read post data)

```
POST https://192.168.0.7/cgi-bin/icul/;stok=554652ca111799826a1fbdafba9d3ac1/remote_command HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 419
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: https://192.168.0.7
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://192.168.0.7/cgi-bin/icul/;stok=554652ca111799826a1fbdafba9d3ac1/smartmomentl/access-point/network
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Cookie: sysauth=f15eff5e9ebb8f152e163f8bc00505c6

command=import&args=%7B%22--json%22%3Atrue%2C%22--force%22%3Atrue%2C%22--mocks%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22DEL%5C%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%5C%22SET%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22dhcp%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22lan%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22.section%5C%22%3A%5C%22dhcp%5C%22%2C%5C%22interface%5C%22%3A%5C%22lan%5C%22%2C%5C%22ignore%5C%22%3A%5C%220%5C%22%2C%5C%22leasetime%5C%22%3A%5C%2212h%5C%22%2C%5C%22range%5C%22%3A%5C%22172.16.0.100-172.16.0.200%5C%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%22%7D

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:09:27 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.30

31
{ "ctx": "No such command", "exitStatus": false }
0
```

NOTE: (6)

## Successful example

[image: Some of them are able to work]

Differences between them I have spotted (by differentiating header contents)

Raw example (* Although path is different from the screen capture, both of them are unable to read post data)

```
POST https://192.168.0.7/cgi-bin/icul/;stok=92dea2b939b9fceb44ac84ac859de7f4/;stok=92dea2b939b9fceb44ac84ac859de7f4/remote_command HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: https://192.168.0.7
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://192.168.0.7/cgi-bin/icul/;stok=92dea2b939b9fceb44ac84ac859de7f4/remote_command/command_reboot
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Cookie: sysauth=683308794904e0bedaaead33acb15c7e

command=command_reboot&args=%7B%22--json%22%3Atrue%7D

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:02:46 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.30

34
{ "ctx": "\u0022success\u0022", "exitStatus": true }
0
```

NOTE: (6)

## Header Difference between 2 examples

- Successful one is using [Jquery binding](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) while failure one using [HTTPS from nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) + browserify. However, I am still finding a way to check whether this is a problem or not (Not tested)
- Missing `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. However, adding this header back to the request does not fix this problem (Tested)
- Capital header vs Smaller letter header field (

  - `content-type` and `Content-type`. However this difference is not the root cause for my problem as tried in [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/4492/) (Tested)
  - `Accept` vs `accept` (Not tested)

NOTE: (5) (7)

Still, I am not sure why the first `c` in `content-type` is in small letter case.

NOTE: (1)

## What I have tried

I have tried on Firefox with firebug. It is able to show my payload. However, it cannot parse response from the server :'(

<s>Since the web server is running in HTTPS protocol, I cannot capture packets by wireshark. Any suggestion for debugging POST requests? Thanks.</s>

Link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mondwan/d8605fe5311ce13e9573) about debugging HTTP(s) request via command line. NOTE: (3)

## Wrapper I am using

I have wrap [this method from nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) with a promise calls. Below is a snippet show an option I have used.

```
/**
 * Wraps HTTPS module from nodejs with Promise
 * @module common/http_request
 */

var createRequestSetting = function (host, path, data, cookies) {
    return {
        method: 'POST',
        port:443,
        host: host,
        path: path,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Content-Type':
                'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
            'Cookie': cookies,
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    };
};
```

[Full source here](http://jsfiddle.net/fpo8d5rv/)

NOTE: (2)

## Update

- (1) I have verified the letter `c` does not affect chrome debugger. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/4492/). I have tried to mimic same request with `XMLHttpRequest` with letter `c`. I can still check form data in the debugger.
- (2) Link to the full source code
- (3) Link to a [gist from me](https://gist.github.com/mondwan/d8605fe5311ce13e9573) about scripts to test HTTP(s) request
- (4) Reformat the question for readability
- (5) Examples are not using the same binding after code reviewing
- (6) Add raw header example
- (7) Add a comparison session

Comment: Also this is only part of the code. There ought to be a `http.request` somewhere? Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js for a complete example

Comment: @geert3 Thanks. For the letter `c`, you can take a look the screenshot of request Header. `content-type` instead of `Content-type`

Comment: For the `separate block` question, there is really no such `block`. The screenshot contains everything in `Headers` tab

Comment: For source code, [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fpo8d5rv/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96648/discussion-between-mond-wan-and-geert3).

Comment: HTTP headers names should be treated in a case-insensitive manner. Some implementations set all-lowercase headers, some don't... when matching headers, either do case-insensitive comparisons or (loop through and) force all header keys to one case.

Comment: Are you using Chrome on Windows Server by any chance? I'm having the same issue and I can see Form Data on Windows 7, but not when I use Chrome on Windows Server.

Comment: Window 7, Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit etc. Both of them are the same according to my memory

Comment: i am there because v98 still periodically unexpected does not show payload(whole tab for several requests)

Answer (score 131):

There was a regression bug in Chrome v61 and v62 across all platforms that caused this behaviour when the response is (amongst others) a 302. This is fixed in v63 stable which was released to all desktop platforms on 6th December 2017.

Automatic updates are phased, but going to "Help" / "About Google Chrome" will force it download the update and give you a button to restart. Occasionally it is necessary to kill all Chrome process and restart it manually to get the update.

The (now closed) bug report is [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766715). The release announcement is [here](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/).

Clearly this is not the cause of the original poster's issue back in 2015, but searches for the issue led me here. Also note this is not just an OS X issue.

Comment: I can confirm this, it is happening on Ubuntu 16.04.1 and Chrome 61

Comment: Windows user. Chrome 61 and Chrome Beta 62. Both have this bug. At first I was communicating with Play server for a login request and I thought there is a "new method" they invented which doesn't appear on Chrome Dev Tools but it turns out its because of Chrome's recession.

Comment: This is still a problem with windows and version 62

Comment: Not sure why using an older browser is "safe".

Comment: He said 'different' browser as opposed to older ie. use Firefox or Edge (but not IE).

Comment: 4 month left and they can't fix the bug, cool. Chromium is dead for developer.

Comment: Is this limited to 302?  I had a 303 w/o form data, and I can see the data posted to the endpoint.

Comment: I am using Chrome 65 beta on a Mac. I am viewing a response with status 200 and I see no request payload section. I viewed the same page with Chrome 63 on Windows and see the payload. Is this issue really fixed?

Comment: I am using 67.0.3396.62 on Mac, I do not see request body.
Is it possibly related to https, not http?

Comment: I have faced this issue on Version `101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 18):

If your application returns a 302 status code, and no payload data in Chrome Devtools, you may be [hitting this Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770130&q=form%20data&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified.).

If you are in development or this is a URL which won't break anything, a quick, very practical, workaround is to modify your server side code to send a 200, for example in PHP you might add:

`die("premature exit - send a 200");`

which sends out a 200 status code. This works around the "302 bug" -- until it is fixed.

p.s. Per @leo-hendry below, Canary does have the fix as of Dec 2017, but if you don't have another reason to run Canary, running another browser side-by-side won't be worth it, as the mainline release should be coming out soon.

Comment: Indeed a bug! When returning 302 and a Location the form data is not showing up (tested with version 61.0.3163.100)

Comment: No. It returns a 200. But anyway, I have resolve it by an alternative in below. Thanks

Comment: also applies to Windows users.

Comment: Thanks @AKCD updated the answer to include all platforms.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a bug it may be behaving differently on Mac vs Windows.

The screenshot below is from Chrome 63 on Windows. You can see the request payload section as expected.

[image: Good Example]

Here is what I see on Chrome 65 Beta running on Mac. Notice the request payload section is missing.

[image: Bad example]

Am I correct to assume that the bug is not fixed or is there something else I should be checking?

Comment: Windows; Google Chrome 66.0.3359.139.
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"> with uploading a file.
In Chrome Debugger->Network I can see only General, Response headers, Request headers and no form data. In **Firefox** I can see the whole POST raw request payload with http request headers+ ALLLLLLL data with uploaded file.

Comment: I can't see it in Chrome (on Mac) latest versions. However last week I could! Don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed that you cannot see POST data if you select "Doc" from the filters in Chrome debugger (next to All, Xhr, Css, JS...). It does show if you select "All".

Comment: Thanks. But I still cannot read POST data no matter what filter I used :'(

Comment: POST requests show in "All" or "Other" filter. I think Chrome shows Form Data only if the response status code is 200 Ok, if it's anything else (e.g.: 302 Found) it will not show it.

Comment: @aeroson wait really? Why? What can I do to get around this?

Comment: @infogulch its actually a bug in Chrome it seems: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770130&q=form%20data&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 3):

I probably got the same problem with the Chrome console (Chrome 69)

Neither the formdata nor the payload tab is showing.
In my scenario I POST a form with enctype "multipart/form-data" to an iframe (submitting an image file over https to the same origin). It works as expected but I don't know how to debug the data in chrome properly when it doesn't show up at all. I *could* dump the data in PHP but that's unnecessary complicated and totally missing the point of using the console. I've read through the suggested solutions above but I didn't manage to get rid of this problem. (The response code is 200 btw, not 302).

[image: Formdata and payload missing]

```
$_POST = Array
(
    [xajax] => 1
    [app] => products
    [cmd] => upload
    [cat] => 575
)

$_FILES = Array
(
    [upfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => Aufkleber_Trollface.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpHwYkKD
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 25692
    )
)
```

Comment: Aye same here - the DevTools vanishing POST bug has returned in Chrome 69 !!

Comment: Probably got fixed as I just started to get downvotes for this. Oooh, stackoverflow... sigh

Comment: @ChrisS. Did you test it again after writing your answer or comment? Because I'm still running into the same problem with current versions of Opera, which is based on somewhat current versions of Chromium. I don't see any POST body even though response code is 200 and it's a plain HTML-form without any JS or fancy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue in Chrome `Version 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

I did not use `formData` for some time, meanwhile, Chrome has been updated

`FormData` has been moved to separate tab `Payload`

[image]

Comment: It's especially easy to miss because the 2nd tab (now the 3rd) was "Preview", and a JSON payload can often look a lot like the JSON response. For example, doing a 'POST' to create a record often returns the same data + the new ID.

Answer (score 1):

check at the client side if payload which you are sending to server is must not
the null

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Hemanth, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Have you checked the Chrome console for errors?
If you have access to the server (and assuming it is `httpd` on Linux) you could make a small CGI shell script to inspect the headers and data at that end:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""    
echo "Hello World. These are my environment variables:"
/usr/bin/env
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" ]; then
    if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "And this is my POST data:"
        /bin/cat
    fi
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: No errors found. However, I found that chrome is able to show `Form data` if `Content-type` is `C` instead of `c`. (same codes but get different `c` :'()

Comment: By the way, thanks for the script. But I believe my problem is not source from server side since `Firefox` can show my input is correct and `Chrome` show my output from server is correct.

Comment: In the above comment you say that it works with `C`, not with `c`. In the original question (update) you say `I have verified the letter c does not affect chrome debugger`. I'm confused. -- Another thought: perpahs one of your chrome extensions/plugins is messing around? Try disabling all extensions.

Comment: I have update the question. it explains what those 2 statement mean. Thanks

Comment: Also, I have tried disabled all extensions I saw at extension page. No luck. It does not fix my problem

Comment: Since you can now catch the HTTPS, can you compare the network traffic in "success" and "failure" cases? Alternatively, you could catch the output of the above CGI-script on both cases. I know server is not the issue, but that way you can really see what is different in the traffic the server receives.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have cross checked headers as you suggested. What I found have been updated in the question. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had another issue, when as well my POST parameters somewhere missed, even in back-end and Chrome Headers, via very simple mistake in code.

I simply wrongly declared params object, as normal array:

```
var params = [];
```

Instead of:

```
var params = {};
```

And then assigned to it params, in result of what, I got no error, but it didn't worked:

```
params['param1'] = 'param1';
params['param2'] = 'param2';

$.post(url, params, function(data) {...
```

In this way, data was not sent or received in back-end, same as not shown because not sent in debugger. It might save for someone hour or few sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime if your form `set enctype="multipart/form-data"`, then Chrome will not catch the request payload.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

[REF](https://superuser.com/a/1577489/1686459)

Answer (score -4):

Although this is not the answer of original question, my alternative is replacing the original implementation with the combo of **form-data**, **es6-promise** and **isomorphic-fetch**

All packages are able to download from npm.

It works charmly.