# req.body does not give the name

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have made a form using 3rd party plugins (multiple and wmd-editor).
My HTML is :

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="post" action="/questions">
    <div id="title" class="form__title">
        <div id="question_title">Title</div>
        <input id="input_element1" class="input_element" type="text" placeholder="What's your programming question? Be specific." name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="text-area">
        <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="wmd-input" name="text"></textarea>
        <div id="wmd-preview"></div>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="inputtags form__tags">
        <select id="options" multiple="multiple" name="tags">
        </select>
        <div class="inputtags__element"></div>
        <div class="inputtags__errors"></div>
        <br>
        <div id="inputtags__post">
            <button class="btn" id="btn-submit">
                Post Your Question
            </button>
            <button class="btn" id="btn-discard">
                Discard
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am putting tags in the options select using the javascript and the javaScript code is:

```
var index = -1;
var htmlStr = tags.reduce(function(a,b){
    index++;
    return a + "<option value="+(index+1)+" name="+b+">"+b+"</option>"; 
},'');
$("#options").html(htmlStr);
```

I am fetching these in the routes file of my node.js (express framework) as :

```
router.post('/questions', function(req,res){
    var question = req.body;
    console.log(question);
    Question.createQuestion(question);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Here req.body should give me the name of DOMs as suggested in [expressjs Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body). I have given name to my option in my javascript code but still when the data is pushed to the database, the req.body return me following:

```
{
    title: 'title',
    text: '<p>Body</p>',
    tags: [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' ]
}
```

My code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you require `body-parser`,  `formidable` or `multer` (any of them) to extract body from `post/put` request when you are using `express` (assuming it)? it is not added in express 4 by default for more https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: @nmrony I did require body-parser.

Comment: What is the sequence of your middleware configuration?

Comment: @nmronyHow can I get that? I am a newbie to node.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using numerical values `<option value="+(index+1)+"` this is what you get.

For `["foo","bar baz"]` your code produces: `<option value=1 name=foo>foo</option><option value=2 name=bar baz>bar baz</option>`

This is very bad html code and will send `1` and `2` as values.

If you want to use the tag strings as values change it to

```
return a + "<option value=\"" + b + "\">" + b + "</option>";
```

to get `<option value="foo">foo</option><option value="bar baz">bar baz</option>` and `["foo", "bar baz"]` as `req.body.tags` on the server.

I removed the `name` property from `option` because it does not do anyhing (you have already defined a `name` for the select tag).

You should only do this if **you** have defined the tags, **never** insert untrusted user input as html code!

Comment: have you refreshed the page? check what your browser is posting using dev tools: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163566/3173842
if your browser posts tags as [1,2,3... this is a client side problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is from a part from `express` boilerplate generated by `express-generator`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
//rest of the code
```

and in `user` router file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/questions', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json(req.body);
});
```

If you do a `POST` call to `/users/questions` using POSTMAN and pass your data as `JSON` you will get it because I just spit it as response. Do not forget to set `Content-Type: application/json` in request header. For file upload you can try [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) or [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme)

for more on `body-parser` please check [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)